# Keras predict only working for one set of variables

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras

I have a series of dependent `X` variables that I want to use to predict `Y`, where `X` vary slightly between each series.

```
    if train=='A':
        pred = df[['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','Y']]
    
    elif train=='B':
        pred = df[['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','Y']]
    
    elif train=='C':
        pred = df[['X1','X2','X3b','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','Y']]
    
    elif train=='D':
        pred = df[['X1','X2','X3b','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','Y']]
    
    elif train == 'E':
        pred = df[['X1','X2b','X3b','X4','X5','X6','X7','X8','Y']]
```

---

And then I try to predict `y` for all vectors above, passing `pred` for 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', sequencially:

```
    ....

    X = pred.drop(axis=1, columns=['Y'])
    # normalize data
    X = X.astype('float32') / 255.
    y = pred['Y']
    # normalize data
    y = y.astype('float32') / 255.

    network = Sequential()

    network.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(8,), activation='relu'))
    network.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
    network.add(Dense(6, activation='relu'))
    network.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    network.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

    network.compile('adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

    network.fit(X, y, epochs=2)

    y_hat = network.predict(X, verbose=1)
```

---

Most of the times, however, predictions fail, and `y_hat` generates an array of `0.000`:

```
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 ..]]
```

except when `train == 'D'`, when network predicts a meaninful array, like so:

```
[[0.00562879]
 [0.00741612]
 [0.0066563 ]
 [0.00720819]
 [0.00596035]
 [0.00612469]
 [0.00808392]
 ....]]
```

---

Any ideas on why my `keras` model prediction works *only* for 'D' variables, *always* on the fourth iteration and to how fix this? Makes no sense to me

PS:

If I run the model only for 'D', it does not work either. So it seems the model 'catches on' after fourth iteration...so I assume it has do do with some initialization process..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe switching `Relu` to `LeaklyReLU` will resolve the issue

From Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent Systems, Aurélien Géron, 2019

> Unfortunately, the ReLU activation function is not perfect. It suffers from a problem known as the dying ReLUs: during training, some neurons effectively “die,” meaning they stop outputting anything other than 0. In some cases, you may find that half of your network’s neurons are dead, especially if you used a large learning rate. A neuron dies when its weights get tweaked in such a way that the weighted sum of its inputs are negative for all instances in the training set. When this happens, it just keeps outputting zeros, and Gradient Descent does not affect it anymore because the gradient of the ReLU function is zero when its input is negative.

You can use `LeaklyReLU` like this

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU # for leakly relu

model.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(8,)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(5))
```

Comment: will try it. do you know the syntax and how to pass the argument? should I import it as `from keras.layers import LeakyReLU`?

Comment: yes, this did it: `keras.layers import LeakyReLU`, then `network.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(8,), activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))`

Comment: @8-BitBorges :) Just edited my post, I'm glad I helped :)